# Understanding to visualize swift initializers

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I am unable to visualise the working of initializers in Swift. For this example from the official documentation.

```
struct Fahrenheit{
   var temp : Double
   init(){
      temp = 32.0
  }
}
var f = Fahrenheit()
print(" \(f.temp)")
//Prints 32.0
```

Here's what I understood till now, PLEASE correct me when i am wrong:

1. struct is a value type.
2. variable temp is a stored property that stores values inside the memory space where the struct is defined (in memory).
3. when we create a variable 'f' is an instance(object) copy of the Structure Fahrenheit is made in another memory space having the same properties.

What i am unable to understand is that what is

```
init(){
          temp = 32.0
      }
```

1. doing to the instance f.
2. When do we use intializers in general. (Main purpose : using an example).
3. Also the difference between functions, closures and initializers, how they are stored in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely important to deeply understand the process of creation of object (as an instance of a class or an instance of the struct). Objects are created based on a template defined in class or struct, in a "space" I like to name as "Object space". So, the object is the instance of struct Fahrenheit in an "Object space" and you could try to see it (visualize) as a balloon. The variable f is a reference to this object and it is been used as a tool to access this balloon (object, instance). 
I suggest you to take a look to Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Here you can see this:

[image: Suggestion, how to visualize it...]

And - In my opinion, it is a good way how to visualize  objects and references to objects.

So, when the system executes: var f = Fahrenheit(),  first - it makes an balloon in Object space, it invokes initialiser (implicit or explicit) to set initial values, than it makes an reference (f) - that points to the just-borned-object.

So:

```
init(){
      temp = 32.0
  }
```

does not make an effect to - f, it makes an effect inside of object (balloon), and f is been uses to access to the balloon. (If there is no reference, the ARC will kill the object)

Comment: So you are saying that, when the f object is created, this object uses some  memory addresses for eg [9000]. And 'f' is used to reference to the memory address [9000].  But i didn't understand "it makes an effect inside of object (balloon)". Thanks !

Comment: Value of temp is within the object. So, initializer makes changes within the object. It does not makes change within f, it makes changes within object - the f refences to.

Comment: f is not an object. It is a reference to the object. f.temp does not mean "value temp in object f", rather it means "value temp of object that f references to". if you write let g = f, you will have two objects and two references if f is an instance of a struct. If f is instance of a class you will have one object, but two references (f and g) to the same object.

Comment: Thanks, Can you tell me when should we use initializers , we can also use default initializing ?

Comment: Of course. Swift requires that properties have values and you can set them when defining properties  like var temp = 20) or using initializers. If you need to implement more complex logic when object starts life cycle, you can define your initializer or more than one of them.